# Output Vbscript info to txt file

Tags: windows, vbscript

Newbie question - I have here a VBScript that looks for an Upgrade Code, and based on that finds the Product Codes for the specified Upgrade Code. The Upgrade Code is always the same, but Product Code changes from version to version, and that can make uninstalling software troublesome. And no, I didn't make this script myself.

This script works very well, but I'd like to make it output all the product codes it found to a text file. I've looked on Google for hours, found some clues, but I've not been able to make it work. Always turns up with a blank text file.

Here's the code:

```
strComputer = "."
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

On Error Resume Next 

Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_Property Where Property = 'UpgradeCode'") 

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware 
    If objSoftware.Value = "{BCCCB25E-C6A6-4340-9018-DA0FB34AF226}" Then
    strCMD = "MsiExec.exe /x " & objSoftware.ProductCode & " /qn"
    objExec = WshShell.Run(strCMD,1,True)
    If objExec <> 0 Then
       WScript.Quit objExec
    End If
    End If
Next
WScript.Quit 0
```

How do I output objSoftware.ProductCode to a text file? Or do I need to output something else to get the Product Codes I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to write text to a file is to `WScript.Echo` the desired info and run the script like `cscript x.vbs > output.txt`.

If that seems to pedestrian, start your research [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your answer. This was one of the first things I tried. However, it doesn't seem to work. I'm probably doing it wrong.

I add this to the code: `WScript.Echo objSoftware.ProductCode` just beneath the strCMD command in my code, but I get no output in the output.txt except the standard "Microsoft (R) Windows Script blablabla".

Any idea what I could change in the echo? objSoftware.ProductCode was my first guess, but no luck there.

Comment: I posted an answer, I made it work. Thanks for your help. I have no idea why it didn't work before, but it works now. Maybe a typo, I don't know, but the code I posted works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Played around with it, Googled it, and I found a solution that works for me. This prints out all the Product Codes on your computer based on the specificed Upgrade Code. Here's the script:

```
strComputer = "."
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

On Error Resume Next 

Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_Property Where Property = 'UpgradeCode'") 

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware 
    If objSoftware.Value = "{BCCCB25E-C6A6-4340-9018-DA0FB34AF226}" Then
    Wscript.Echo objSoftware.ProductCode
    strCMD = "MsiExec.exe /x " & objSoftware.ProductCode & " /qn"
    objExec = WshShell.Run(strCMD,1,True)
    If objExec <> 0 Then
       WScript.Quit objExec
    End If
    End If
Next
WScript.Quit 0
```

Running `//NoLogo scriptname.vbs > log.txt` in command prompt, gives me a txt file with all the product codes for the upgrade code specified.

Please note this code also uninstalls the software afterwards.